# Is there a way to update a DataTable with criteria?

Tags: c#, .net

Instead of going through each row to update a DataTabe, is there something to update a DataTable in C# like what SQL statement does:

```
   DataTable table = new  DataTable;
   .................................
   table.Update("columnname1>xxx And columnname1<yyy",columnname3='zzz'"); 
 //        |                  |                                 |   
 //  Certain Function       criteria                        set values
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using SQL-like syntax, but you could use Linq:

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("columnname1") > xxx 
                                        && r.Field<int>("columnname1") < yyy);
foreach(var r in rows)
{
    r.columnname3="zzz";
}
```